# Train and test split set using ImageDataGenerator and flow

Tags: keras, data-augmentation, train-test-split

I'm trying to make a network using augmentation.

First I use ImageDataGenerator with validation_split=0.2.

```
train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=90,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    fill_mode="nearest",
    validation_split=0.2
)
```

Then I tried to create a augmented training data end a not augmented validation data.
I have to use `flow` instead of `flow_from_directory`.

```
train_augm = train_generator.flow([data_train, ebv_train], z_train, batch_size=128,subset='training')
valid_augm = train_generator.flow([data_train, ebv_train], z_train, batch_size=1,subset='validation')
```

I get this error menssage.

```
ValueError: Training and validation subsets have different number of classes after the split. If your numpy arrays are sorted by the label, you might want to shuffle them.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

The model.fit code is something like this

```
training_history = model.fit(
    train_augm,
    steps_per_epoch= len(data_train)//128,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=valid_augm    
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of classes in the training data is not equal to the number of classes in the validation data. If you didn't shuffle it, please shuffle it. If you're still getting the error, I am assuming that some of the class has a very small number of data. you can reshuffle it, but sometimes you will get the same error. What you can do is, add more data to that specific class or manually split into training and validation.

For random split, you can take a look at train_test_split library.